# Rearrange the components of filenames for a group of files

Tags: bash, files, rename, filename

I have a group of photo files that are named: `ddmmyyyyxxxx.jpg` (xxxx is just a sequence number) that I am trying to search but sadly no results, is to rename the filename to `yyyy-mm-dd-xxxx.jpg`.

All that I can find on the net is either replacing certain character or changing the letters case.

Comment: In a flat directory or recursivly?

Comment: flat directory @JacobVlijm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do that using *capture groups* with the perl-based `rename` command e.g. at its simplest

```
rename -vn -- 's/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/$3-$2-$1/' *.jpg
```

(Note: the `-n` is a dry-run flag: it won't actually change anything unless you remove that.)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using the following bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(ls)
do
    date=${file:0:2}
    month=${file:2:2}
    year=${file:4:4}
    sequence=${file:8:4}
    extension=${file: -3}

    mv $file $year\-$month\-$date\-$sequence.$extension
done
echo all files have been renamed
```

In order to use this script, open a terminal and type `touch script` followed by `chmod +x script` to make it executable. Then run `nano script` and copy paste the code above into the terminal. save the file by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, follwed by <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>enter</kbd>. Then move the script to the directory containing these images and execute the script by running `./script`.

This will rename all the files in the in the directory of the script to the pattern you requested. However it will also rename the script itself so if you want to run the script again, just note it will have a different name( it will end up being `pt-ri-sc-.ipt` I would recommend you run `mv pt-ri-sc-.ipt script` before using the script again. Other wise you could replace `ls` with `ls $1` and store the script somewhere else to avoid renaming it by accident.
Also this script will only run properly for files that have names in the sequence given in the question(`ddmmyyyyxxxx.jpg`). For any other files the file will end up with some weird name.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of procedure I use Krename, it has a GUI and is slightly intuitive… Under ubuntu you find it in the Software Center.